# Calculating using Assembly with signed values

Tags: assembly, x86-64

So for the question below:

**Suppose x, y, and z are declared as quadwords and contain signed values. Write the assembly code that calculates the result of the following expression and leaves the result in the EAX register.**

***`(x + y) / (y / z)`***

has to be done with NASM x86-64, and I wanted to make sure if this logical instruction would make sense for the question above. It says leaving the result in EAX so I figured everything has to be done by E registers. If anyone could double-check, let me know, or if there are things to fix/improve.

And one other thing, it doesn't need to be a full-fleshed-out code. I already have all the declarations and functions outside this short segment of the instructional logic code so just assume I already have them defined.

```
mov ecx, [x]
mov edx, [y]
mov esi, [z]

;MATH
add ecx, edx ; (x+y)
cdq ; 32 byte register
mov eax, edx
idiv esi ; (y/z)
mov edx, eax 
mov eax, ecx ; (x+y) into eax
cdq
idiv ecx ; (x+y)/z
```

Comment: _"I wanted to make sure if this logical instruction would make sense for the question above"_ Have you tested the code to see if it produces the expected result?

Comment: Doing `cdq` _before_ `mov eax, edx` seems like a mistake though. Note that `cdq` modifies `edx`.

Comment: @Michael Yep! Just wanted to get your takes just from reading this without using replit; a sensible piece of code that would make sense on the question in hand. Yep and I'll get that fixed. Is there anything else you see as a fault?

Comment: @Michael Also I assume cdq should be placed after `mov eax, edx` correct?

Comment: If x,y,z are quadwords then they need to be loaded into 64-bit registers (rcx, rdx, etc).  It sounds to me like the question expects you to do the arithmetic on 64-bit quantities and then truncate to 32 bits at the end (or just leave a 64-bit result in `rax` and let the calling code ignore the high half).

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm kinda effy on. Not sure where to go from here to truncate to 32-bits through EAX register.

Comment: As I said in the parenthetical, there isn't really anything to do.  If you end up with the 64-bit result in `rax` (as you naturally will if you finish with a 64-bit `idiv`), then the low 32 bits of it are `eax` and you are done.  Truncation is more a mathematical expression of what's happening than anything about specific instructions.

Comment: @NateEldredge So its okay the way it is, just change E registers to R registers? Because the question "leave the result in the EAX register." had the notion of coding all of the code in E registers.

Comment: I know, that is a strange requirement to produce a 32-bit output when the inputs are 64 bits.  It might be a mistake by whoever wrote the exercise, and if it's up to you, you could interpret it as "leave the result in RAX" instead.  But otherwise, I think the most natural interpretation is what I said.  For instance, if `y = 0x200000000` and `z = 0x100000000`, then I think you would expect `y/z` to yield 2, instead of a divide-by-zero fault as your current code would do. In which case yes, change all E registers to R registers, and `cdq -> cqo` as vitsoft explained.

Comment: @NateEldredge Gotcha, thank you so much for the guidance. By the way, do you think the question might be asking a way to transition from R registers to E registers, in this case, leaving the result into `EAX` in some way, or is that just not possible without changing the 64-bit inputs to E registers?

Comment: This is what I've been trying to explain, several times.  EAX is the low half of RAX, so if you leave your 64-bit result in RAX, any code looking for a 32-bit result in EAX will find the low half of the result.  If the result was in the range of a 32-bit signed integer, -2147483648 to 2147483647, then the low half will be the mathematically correct 32-bit result.  If not, it will be correct mod 2^32.  So what I'm suggesting **is** "leaving the result in EAX "in some way"  - in the way that I think is most reasonable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Got it. Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Commenting each instruction with the expected effect will help:

```
mov ecx, [x]      ; ecx = x
mov edx, [y]      ; edx = y
mov esi, [z]      ; esi = z

;MATH             ; eax is undefined garbage!
add ecx, edx      ; ecx = (x+y)
cdq               ; edx:eax = eax  ; overwrites edx with 0 or -1
mov eax, edx      ; eax = either 0 or -1
idiv esi          ; eax = (garbage / z), edx = remainder of garbage
mov edx, eax      ; edx = garbage
mov eax, ecx      ; eax = (x+y)
cdq               ; edx:eax = (x+y) 
idiv ecx          ; eax= (x+y) / (x+y) = 1, edx = remainder 0
```

As you can see, using `edx` for holding values is not a good idea when division is required. Instructions `idiv` or `div` expect dividend in register-pair `edx:eax` and they overwrite `eax` with the result (quotient) and `edx` with the remainder.
`cdq` should be used to extend the signed value from `eax` to the pair `edx:eax` before each division.

Choose another register for the **y** value. As Nate mentioned, for quadword values you'll need 64bit registers. Instead of `cdq` you'll need `cdo` to sign-extend `rax` to `rdx:rax`.  When the final result fits to 32 bits,  you can leave it in `eax` *as is*, but it's usual for 64bit function to return `rax`.

Comment: I made some change and fixes. Check the answers for my post of the new program, thank you

Comment: @Atlas Yes, I have completed you answer with comments of each instruction and now it seems to be OK, provided that **x,y,z** are doublewords and not quadwords and that no overflow occurs.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I was wondering about that. So I should just change the E registers into R registers correct? My confusion is that the general notion from the critique seems to be to change the registers to 64-bit, but not sure how I would leave that into EAX register for the result. Or I might just be comprehending the replies wrong, so sorry in advance.

Comment: @Atlas Exactly, for quadwords just use `R*` instead of `E*` registers and `cdo` instead of `cdq`. You've managed to correct all mistakes in your own answer.  If it is a homework, you might be expected to handle overflows (with `jo error`) after addition and divisions.

Comment: Much appreciated for your help! By any chance, is there some way to transition the R register to leave the result into the E register, in this case, `EAX`? Or is there really no way to change it without changing the whole program into E registers? The question itself is very contradicting so just want to double-check.

Comment: @Atlas You could test  whether the final result in `rax` does not overflow `eax`: bits 31..63 of `rax` ought to be all zeros or all ones, in this case the signed integer  value in `eax` is the same as in `rax`.  Yes the assignment is incomplete, it doesn't specify if the operater **/** is integer division or real division, and how overflow should be signalized.

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify through visual representation? I changed the declaration to `ecx` from `edx`, and fixed `cdq`. I'm still not sure how to go about transitioning R registers and placing the result into EAX

```
 mov ebx,[x]   ; ebx = x
  mov ecx,[y]  ; ecx = y
  mov esi,[z]  ; esi = z

  add ebx,ecx  ; ebx = (x+y)
  mov eax,ecx  ; eax = y
  cdq          ; edx:eax = y
  idiv esi     ; eax = (y/z) ; edx = remainder
  mov ecx,eax  ; ecx = (y/z)
  mov eax,ebx  ; eax = (x+y)
  cdq          ; edx:eax = (x+y)
  idiv ecx     ; eax = (x+y) / (y/z)
```

Comment: Generally requests for clarifications should go in comments, or as an edit to the question, not as an answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for telling me. I'm new here so I will do that going on forward.

Comment: @vitsoft I have made a response, not sure if you're getting the notification for it